Quarkus Azure File upload not working correctly
Im trying to upload an image through my backend to azure blob storage.
However the image size is 0 when viewing in Microsoft Azure Storage explorer
Uploading the image to my backend works as it should.
When saving the image locally. The image data has a proper size and gets displayed.
However, when uploading to Azure Blob Storage, the image has a size of 0 in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.
Im also using Azurite for simulating the environment.
@POST
    @Path("upload-image")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Uni<Response> uploadImage(@MultipartForm FormData formData) {
        String uniqueFileName = "wearyimage-" + UUID.randomUUID() + "-" + LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")) + "-" + formData.getFileName();
        Log.info("Uploading image: " + formData.getFileName() + " at " + LocalDateTime.now());
        Log.info("Unique file name: " + uniqueFileName);



        try {
            Log.info("Actual file size: " + formData.file.available());
            File localFile = new File("testFiles", uniqueFileName);
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(localFile)) {
                BinaryData binaryData = BinaryData.fromStream(formData.getFile(), formData.getFileSize());
                byte[] bytes = binaryData.toBytes();
                out.write(bytes);
            }
            Log.info("File saved locally: " + localFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.error("Failed to save file locally", e);
        }



        Mono<BlockBlobItem> blockBlobItem = blobServiceAsyncClient.createBlobContainerIfNotExists("images")
                .map(blobContainerAsyncClient -> blobContainerAsyncClient.getBlobAsyncClient(uniqueFileName))
                .flatMap(blobAsyncClient -> {
                    InputStream inputStream = formData.getFile();
                    long fileSize = formData.getFileSize();
                    Log.info(BinaryData.fromStream(inputStream,fileSize).getLength());
                    return blobAsyncClient.upload(BinaryData.fromStream(inputStream, fileSize));
                });
        return Uni.createFrom().completionStage(blockBlobItem.toFuture()).map(it -> Response.status(CREATED).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(Map.of("filename", uniqueFileName)).build());
    }



When saving the image locally. The image data has a proper size and gets displayed. However, when uploading to Azure Blob Storage, the image has a size of 0 in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer,

As you said the image data has a proper size and gets displayed in local environment. Now, you can use the below code to upload image file from local to azure blob storage with blobAsyncClient.uploadFromFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath()); using Azure Java SDK.
Code:
 Mono<BlockBlobItem> blockBlobItem = blobServiceAsyncClient.createBlobContainerIfNotExists("images")
            .map(blobContainerAsyncClient -> blobContainerAsyncClient.getBlobAsyncClient(uniqueFileName))
            .flatMap(blobAsyncClient -> {
                File localFile = new File("testFiles", uniqueFileName);
                long fileSize = localFile.length();
                Log.info("File size before upload: " + fileSize);
                return blobAsyncClient.uploadFromFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
            });
    return Uni.createFrom().completionStage(blockBlobItem.toFuture())
            .map(it -> {
                BlobProperties properties = it.getProperties();
                long contentLength = properties.getContentLength();
                Log.info("File size after upload: " + contentLength);
                return Response.status(CREATED)
                        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .entity(Map.of("filename", uniqueFileName))
                        .build();
            })
            .onFailure().invoke(throwable -> {
                Log.error("Failed to upload file to Azure Blob Storage", throwable);
            });

Portal:

Reference:

BlobAsyncClient Class | Microsoft Learn
Upload a file to azure blob storage met an error using java - Stack Overflow by me.

